# How do I draw lines inside a Visual C++ PictureBox

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I want to draw black lines inside a Visual C++ Forms PictureBox to plot some information. Can How should I go about doing this? Can a PictureBox be used to do this or should I use something else instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw on any WinForms control, handle the [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event, get the [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) object, and call [DrawLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLine.aspx) or [other methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics_methods.aspx) to your heart's content.

There's a good example of this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx?cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2).